How to get exactly the same div elements order in my jQuery converted code from a working mootools code?
I am trying to convert a working mootools code into jQuery equivalent. Code is for a sticky sliding menu on top of web page and the conversion is needed just because the same code is to be used in a Joomla! version >= 4 based web site, where mootools has been dropped in favour of jQuery.
In principle, the converted jQuery code do its job, except that an added <div>...</div> element is inserted in a different place when comparing to the original mootools output and because of the different css order, the final style (a height in his case) gives a different cosmetic result.
This is the function code for each versions:
// mootools (original based)
setDesktopSticky: function(menuId) {
    var header = document.id(menuId ? menuId : 'custom-menu');

    window.addEvent('load', function() {
        var headerPosition = header.getPosition(),
            menuHeight = header.getHeight(),
            placeHolder = new Element('div', {'class': 'custom-menu-placeholder'});

        window.addEvent('scroll', function(event) {
            var windowScroll = window.getScroll();

            if (windowScroll.y > headerPosition.y) {
                header.addClass('custom-menu-sticky');
                placeHolder.inject(header, 'after');
                placeHolder.setStyle('height', menuHeight);
            } else {
                header.removeClass('custom-menu-sticky');
                placeHolder.destroy();
            }
        });
    });
},

//jQuery (converted)
setDesktopSticky: function(menuId) {
    var header = jQuery(this).is(menuId) ? menuId : jQuery("#custom-menu")[0];

    jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
        var headerPosition = jQuery(header).position().top,
            menuHeight = jQuery(header).height(),
            placeHolder = jQuery("<div/>", {"class": "custom-menu-placeholder"})[0];

        jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {
            var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

            if (windowScroll > headerPosition) {
                jQuery(header).addClass("custom-menu-sticky");
                jQuery(placeHolder).appendTo(header);
                jQuery(placeHolder).css("height", menuHeight);
            } else {
                jQuery(header).removeClass("custom-menu-sticky");
                jQuery(placeHolder).remove();
            }
        });
    });
},

And this is the output from each versions, as viewed with the browser inspect tool; the line in question is the one containing ... class="custom-menu-placeholder" ...:
// page inspect for mootools generated output
// ...
▼ <div id="custom-page" class="container"> // [div flashes here when scroll]
    ::before
    ► <div id="custom-header" class="row-fluid">...</div>
    ▼ <div id="custom-menu" class="custom-menu-sticky">
        ► <div id="custom-menu_inner">...</div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-menu-placeholder" style="height: 54px;"></div>
    ► <div id="custom-body">...</div>
    // etc.

// page inspect for jquery generated output
// ...
▼ <div id="custom-page" class="container">
    ::before
    ► <div id="custom-header" class="row-fluid">...</div>
    ▼ <div id="custom-menu" class="custom-menu-sticky"> // [div flashes here when scroll]
        ▼ <div id="custom-menu_inner">
            ► <div id="custom-menu_inner1">...</div>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-menu-placeholder" style="height: 53px;"></div>
        </div>
    ► <div id="custom-body">...</div>
    // etc.

Other difference is that the browser inspect tool flashes a different div when scrolling (i.e. when web page code changes dynamically), marked above by me with "// [div flashes here when scroll]" (for clarity I didn't mentioned the other flashes that matches same places).
So, question – what is wrong or what should be modified in my converted code in order to obtain the same output on the generated web page ? I don't have jQuery coding experience, so it's very likely that I'm wrong somewhere.

In the original version, header referred to an HTML element - but now you got either an ID, or an element stored in there. Assuming it is the former case, jQuery(placeHolder).appendTo(header); would likely need to be jQuery(placeHolder).appendTo(jQuery(header)); instead.

In both code versions, the locally defined header var object variable gives ► <div id="custom-menu" class="custom-menu-sticky">...</div> when spying it as text in console. Probably I made a confusion about it. Anyway, your suggestion with .appendTo(jQuery(header)) does not change a thing.

Then please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, at least for the jQuery version.

Ok, will try (only that not right away)

Are you sure you didn't make a copy-and-paste error when you've pasted your HTML example? Because the latter one contains an extra closing </div> that seems to belong nowhere and sits right after the <div> with the class custom-menu-placeholder.

I checked – no error: the <div id="custom-menu_inner"> closes with the first floating </div> and the <div id="custom-menu" class="custom-menu-sticky"> closes with the second floating </div>. Do I miss something ? (the first line with the container class closes later far below)

Yeah, you're right. I got confused by the inner <div class="custom-menu_inner1"> element. Sorry!

Your "jQuery translation" has a few bits that are either unnecessary or different to what the original mootools code did.
First off, the line
var header = jQuery(this).is(menuId) : menuId : jQuery('#custom-menu');

should be the following for a 1:1 match:
var header = jQuery(menuId ? '#' + menuId : '#custom-menu');

The reason is the same that @CBroe mentioned in the first comment: With the upper line you end up with either a jQuery collection or with a simple String. The lower line addresses that.
Then, it's completely unnecessary to repeatedly wrap the the same elements into new jQuery collections once you have them. Instead, you can reuse the collections that you already have. Meaning you don't need
jQuery(header).position().top

because header is a jQuery collection already and you get away with
header.position().top

instead. In contrast to mootools (which augmented the prototypes of built-in objects and therefor got away with returning the actual object itself), jQuery works with a so-called "jQuery collection" (an array-like structure, it has a .length and stores node via index position but isn't a real Array). Once you wrapped an element/some elements into a jQuery collection, you can refer to that collection for further manipulation.
Those two things simplify your jQuery code quite a bit:
setDesktopSticky: function(menuId) {
  var header = jQuery(menuId ? "#" + menuId : "#custom-menu"),
      win = jQuery(window);

  win.on("load", function() {
    var headerPosition = header.position().top,
        menuHeight = header.height(),
        placeHolder = jQuery("<div/>", {"class": "custom-menu-placeholder"});

    win.scroll(function(event) {
      var windowScroll = win.scrollTop();

      if (windowScroll > headerPosition) {
        header.addClass("custom-menu-sticky");
        placeHolder.appendTo(header).css("height", menuHeight); // <-- Note the chained calls
      } else {
         header.removeClass("custom-menu-sticky");
         placeHolder.remove();
      }
    });
  });
}

Just by reading it seems the reason why the height set by mootools compared with the one set by jQuery is different because mootools used .getBoundingClientRect() under the hood while jQuery uses Math.max combined with either .clientHeight, .offsetHeight and .scrollHeight. See mootools implementation, line 80 and jQuery implementation, line 37.
EDIT
Based on your comment, you don't want to use .appendTo in the line
placeHolder.appendTo(header).css("height", menuHeight);

and instead use .insertAfter
placeHolder.insertAfter(header).css("height", menuHeight);

The former one adds the placeholder element as the last child inside the header while the latter one adds it after the header.

(just guessing) While I understand the different computing methods for height, in this case it is not the height itself that makes a difference (its value is practically the same on both), but an otherwise identical <div>...</div> line that is placed differently, with this one – as it seems to me – because of different computing method for inject (mootools) versus appendTo (jQuery).

Well, then just use the appropriate jQuery method. I've updated the answer to reflect that change.

Well, yes, that solved the trouble :) Before posting here I searched in various ways trying to find out if there are several kinds of append/insert/whatever methods, but obviously I didn't searched the right way. Thank you!
